# Python plot Large matrix using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, matrix, out-of-memory, large-data

I am trying to plot a matrix with 2000 columns and 200000 rows. I can test plot and test export the matrix figure fine when the matrix is small using

```
matshow(my_matrix)
show()
```

However, when more rows are added to my_matrix, the figure becomes very narrow as there are way more rows than columns, thus losing the precision when zooming in. Can I make matrix figure scrollable? If not, how can I visualize such matrix without losing precision?

I also tried to call savefig('filename', dpi=300) in order to save the image without losing too much precision, but it throws MemoryError when the matrix is big. Many thanks!

Comment: Maybe too simple for your needs, but have you tried splitting up your large matrix into parts, and then calling matshow on each of those?

Comment: `ax.set_aspect('auto')` will fix the aspect problem, but your pixels will be rectangles not squares.  I have done things with 2k x 150k, but it is starting to push the limits of what mpl can do (there are some hard-coded 32 bit integers in the c++ rasterization code).

Comment: @tcaswell matshow() returns a AxesImage. I believe the  set_aspect()  function is only accessible to Axes object. I don't know how to get the Axes object from AxesImage.

Comment: I ended up taking a combination of your suggestions. Get current axes by calling ax = plt.gca() then ax.set_aspect('auto'), I also split the matrix into smaller matrices.

Comment: Hi @emily - consider adding an answer to your own question so that people in the future with the same problem can find it easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up taking a combination of @tcaswell and @lesnikow's suggestions.

Get current axes in order to set auto aspect ratio properly, I also split the matrix into smaller matrices:

```
    import matplotlib.pylab as plt

    for j in range(lower_bound_on_rows, upper_bound_on_rows): nums.append(j)
    partial_matrix = my_matrix[nums, :] 

    plt.matshow(partial_matrix, fignum=100)
    plt.gca().set_aspect('auto')
    plt.savefig('filename.png', dpi=600)
```

My matrix is long vertically, so I sliced by rows and preserved all columns in the smaller matrices. If your matrix is long horizontally, flip the index like this my_matrix[:, nums]